# Hyperlink based on two dynamic cell values

Tags: excel, hyperlink, excel-formula, google-sheets

first time I don't find the answer in an open thread.

I would like to create a hyperlink in a dynamic generated cell, based on a dynamic value of another cell:

The values in D are a generated URLs based on a static value (i.e. www.example.com) + the username in A (i.e. /user1). The result would be here www.example.com/user1. Now I would like to have the username in A directly as hyperlink so "User1" from A would link to www.example.com/user1.

Is there a way to have this done in the same cell? If not, how would that look if I would ad a column E for the username with a hyperlink?

Thanks a lot,
David

[Example mentioned in this questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqQ3S.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to replace the contents of `column A` using formulas. However you can have the link generated using formula in a separate column. For example, in cell `D2` or `E2` enter the below formula,

```
=HYPERLINK("http://www.example.com/"&A2,"example")
```

drag it down to generate for all user names present in `column A`. Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Works perfectly fine! Thanks a mil for the quick response, much appreciated :)

Comment: @user8014703 thats great !!